# Email enviado com PHP chegando em branco

Tags: php, html

tenho um formulário para cadastro de currículo de uma determinada empresa, as ID do HTML está tudo e o Código PHP esta em anexo. só chega as informações que esta escrito, não esta pegando os valores dos input ou select. alguem sabe me dizer se é por causa da quantidade de Campos? porque são 44 Campos, desde já agradeço.

```js
<?php
/* e-mail que vai receber os curriculos */
$myemail  = "samuelnicolau044@gmail.com";

/* checando e pegando todos os campos do FORM */


/* DADOS PESSOAIS */
$nomedapessoa     = check_input($_POST['nomedapessoa']);
$CPF              = check_input($_POST['CPF']);
$nascimento       = check_input($_POST['nascimento']);
$generopessoal    = check_input($_POST['generopessoal']);
$estcivil         = check_input($_POST['estcivil']);
$habilitacao      = check_input($_POST['habilitacao']);
$dependentes      = check_input($_POST['dependentes']);
$deficiencia      = check_input($_POST['deficiencia']);


/*   ENDEREÇO  */
$CEP              = check_input($_POST['CEP']);
$logradouro       = check_input($_POST['logradouro']);
$complemento      = check_input($_POST['complemento']);
$bairro           = check_input($_POST['bairro']);
$cidade           = check_input($_POST['cidade']);
$estados          = check_input($_POST['estados']);
$email            = check_input($_POST['email']);
$telefone         = check_input($_POST['telefone']);
$horario          = check_input($_POST['horario']);


/* FORMAÇÃO */
$nomecurso        = check_input($_POST['nomecurso']);
$nivelcurso       = check_input($_POST['nivelcurso']);
$situacao         = check_input($_POST['situacao']);
$area             = check_input($_POST['area']);
$instituicao      = check_input($_POST['instituicao']);


/* CURSOS COMPLEMENTARES */
$nomedocurso      = check_input($_POST['nomedocurso']);
$situacao         = check_input($_POST['situacao']);
$areacurso        = check_input($_POST['areacurso']);
$instituçaocurso  = check_input($_POST['instituçaocurso']);
$conclusaocurso   = check_input($_POST['conclusaocurso']);


/* IDIOMAS */
$idioma           = check_input($_POST['idioma']);
$situaçãoidioma   = check_input($_POST['situaçãoidioma']);
$nivelconversacao = check_input($_POST['nivelconversacao']);
$nivelleitura     = check_input($_POST['nivelleitura']);
$nivelescrita     = check_input($_POST['nivelescrita ']);
$instituicaoidioma= check_input($_POST['instituicaoidioma']);
$conclusaoidioma  = check_input($_POST['conclusaoidioma']);


/* EXPERIENCIA PROFISSIONAL */
$nomedaempresa   = check_input($_POST['nomedaempresa']);
$cargo           = check_input($_POST['cargo']);
$atribuicoes     = check_input($_POST['atribuicoes']);
$salariofixo     = check_input($_POST['salariofixo']);
$empregoatual    = check_input($_POST['empregoatual']);


/*  OBJETIVOS   */
$salarioatual    = check_input($_POST['salarioatual']);
$salariopret     = check_input($_POST['salariopret']);


/* INFORMAÇÕES ADCIONAIS */

$viagem        = check_input($_POST['viagem']);
$outracidade   = check_input($_POST['outracidade']);


/* TERMOS DE USO  */

$termos        = check_input($_POST['termos']);







/* se a URL não é válida */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Corpo do E-mail */
$message = "Olá Você tem um Novo Currículo Cadastrado!

         $nomedapessoa
       CPF - $CPF

       
$nascimento , $estcivil , $generopessoal


_____Endereço_____ 

CEP - $CEP

$logradouro - $complemento - $bairro

$cidade - $estados

_____Contato_____

Email    - $email 
Telefone - $telefone
Melhor Horário para contato - $horario 




_____Formação_____

Curso       - $nomecurso

Nível       - $nivelcurso

Situação    - $situacao
 
Área        - $area

Instituição - $instituicao



_____Cursos Complementares_____

Nome - $nomedocurso

Situação - $situacao

Área - $areacurso 

Instituição - $instituçaocurso

Conclusão - $conclusaocurso



_____Idiomas_____

Idioma - $idioma

Instituição - $instituçaocurso

Situação - $situaçãoidioma

Conclusão - $conclusaoidioma

Leitura  - $nivelleitura  
Conversa - $nivelconversacao
Escrita  - $nivelescrita



_____Experiência Profissional_____

Empresa - $nomedaempresa

Cargo   - $cargo

Atribuições -  $atribuicoes




Salário Fixo - $salariofixo 

Emprego Atual - $empregoatual




_____OBJETIVO_____

Salário Atual - $salarioatual

Sálario Pretendido - $salariopret



_____Informações Adicionais_____

Possui Habilitação - $habilitacao

Possui Deficiência - $deficiencia  

Possui Dependentes - $dependentes



$nomedapessoa , $termos


      
";














/* Enviar o e-mail usando função main() */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Quando o e-mail for eviado com sucesso, redirecionar para de agradecimento */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

/* Funções que eu usei */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)  
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Erro</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sugiro que use a biblioteca phpmailer

Comment: vou inserir ela aqui, e já te falo. obrigado

Comment: Tentei unserir ela ainda continua chegando em branco

Comment: Você está recebendo os inputs corretamente?

Comment: estou recebendo somente o que eu escrevi, por exemplo:

Comment: nome : $nomedapessoa , so está vindo o nome , o que foi digitado no input não está vindo